# How to remove last SENTENCE in string if it ends with a certain character?

Tags: python-3.x, list, join, split

This is going to be something really basic but I have forgotten how to do it. I just want to remove the last line of each string in a list if it ends with ':'. I have

```
desc1 = ['A sentence. Another sentence', 'One more sentence. A sentence that finishes with:', 'One last sentence. This also finishes with a:']
for string in desc1:
    if string.endswith(':'):
        a = string.split('.')
        b = a[:-1]
        c = '.'.join(map(str, b))
        print (c)
```

At the moment that prints:

```
One more sentence
One last sentence
```

How do I now get it so that it prints the following:

```
['A sentence. Another sentence', 'One more sentence.', 'One last sentence.']
```

Answer (score 2):

Not terribly robust but hopefully something to get you moving in the right direction:

```
strings = ['A sentence. Another sentence', 'One more sentence. A sentence that finishes with:', 'One last sentence. This also finishes with a:']

new_strings = []

for string in strings:
    if string.endswith(':'):
                sentences = string.split('.')
                string = '.'.join(sentences[:-1]) + '.'

    new_strings.append(string)

print(new_strings)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
['A sentence. Another sentence', 'One more sentence.', 'One last sentence.']
>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:-

```
var descFinal = [];
for(var i=0; i< desc1.length; i++){
  if(desc1[i].endsWith(":")){
   descFinal.push(desc1[i].substring(0, desc1[i].lastIndexOf('.') + 1));
  }else{
    descFinal.push(desc1[i])
  }
}
```

Comment: This... is java. Did you see the question?